# WP Admin bar and header move when scrolling down

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I've looked all over and can't find the correct solution.

Problem:
My WP admin bar and main header is fixed, but when scrolling up the admin bar and main header come down. See picture.

[image: scrolling up]

When scrolling down the WP admin bar disappears a little bit, see picture.
[image]

What can I do so it always stays in place?

Comment: try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36898/admin-bar-and-fixed-header-issue

Answer (score 0):

When you login to your site that time admin bar show on the front side and that time WordPress has added the 2 class in the body. please check to inspect element and see the `<body class="logged-in admin-bar">` Now you can add the style in this class like below.

[image]

If you fix or not fix so you can write your code in this style like margin, padding etc

```
.logged-in.admin-bar{

/*Put code*/

}
```

Comment: I don't have this logged-in.admin-bar

Comment: ok you can edit your header.php in your theme and add the `body_class();` in your `<body>` like `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` after check

Comment: `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` after check inspect element this class have added

Comment: Ok, now I have it :) The problem isn't to get the admin bar fixed but when I scroll down it moves....but when I stop scrolling it goes back to the top.